# Is it safe to give a temporary address ( assigned in a While block ) to a global ListNode?

Tags: java, jvm, memory-address

Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/solution/#

```
class Solution {
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(0);
ListNode p = l1, q = l2, curr = dummyHead;
int carry = 0;
while (p != null || q != null) {
    int x = (p != null) ? p.val : 0;
    int y = (q != null) ? q.val : 0;
    int sum = carry + x + y;
    carry = sum / 10;
    curr.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
    curr = curr.next;
    if (p != null) p = p.next;
    if (q != null) q = q.next;
}
if (carry > 0) {
    curr.next = new ListNode(carry);
}
return dummyHead.next;
}
}
```

Hi everyone, this morning I met a problem on LeetCode. I solved it yet want to raise a question towards the official solution.

I know referring to a variable defined in a function is not safe( because it will be recycled). However, to my best knowledge, those variables which **defined in code blocks like while/for** should also be recycled by JVM. Although JVM will not recycle it for there are still pointers pointing at the address, I wonder **if it's still not safe to give a temporary address to a global ListNode here**?

```
curr.next = new ListNode(carry);
```

After all, I wonder if the ListNode has to be frequently watched by JVM for using a temporary address, resulting in extra time consumption?

Thanks! I also discussed the above in the problem's discussion in Leetcode, but I really want to know if I'm considering too much?

Comment: I think you're confusing a number of things. C is not Java and references are not the objects that they point to. One concrete thing I can address: `curr.next = new ListNode(carry);` is safe, and the JVM does not need to watch ListNode any more frequently than any other object created anywhere in your Java code.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “temporary address” in Java. There’s not even a thing like “address” on the language level. The whole point of the language design is that you are not able to do a thing that “is not safe”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can assume that you have been used with Java language (like you already coded C)
About your concern, i can sum up

1. Your concern is that

   > curr.next = new ListNode(carry);

   that curr could be recycled by java GC which might cause access next raise exception? => Don't worry about it. The curr is only collected after addTwoNumbers() executed (at least).
2. So your question

   > if it's still not safe to give a temporary address to a global ListNode here?

   => No it is safe. You simple construct a new object, it is fine.
3. Next concern about

   > the ListNode has to be frequently watched by JVM for using a temporary address, resulting in extra time consumption?

   As I see, there is no extra time consumption in your assigment.